# Update same field in SQL based on different criteria in AS400 SQL

Tags: sql, select, db2, sql-update, ibm-midrange

A question recently came up on whether it's possible to perform an update on the same field in the file based on 2 different criteria.  We introduced a step to run 2 different SQL's at the end of day processing, so the initial problem has been relieved.  However, for my own knowledge on the subject, I'm curious if it is possible to do one SQL statement similar to the below?

```
UPDATE MYFILE 
SET FIELD1 = 'ABC' where FIELD2 = '123' and FIELD3 = '456',
SET FIELD1 = 'XYZ' where FIELD2 = '789' and FIELD3 = '123'
```

Is something like that possible within one statement, or would you have to break it out in 2 statements like we ended up doing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression within the `update` statement:

```
update myfile
set field1 = case
    when field2 = '123' and field3 = '456' then 'abc'
    when field2 = '789' and field3 = '123' then 'xyz'
end
where 
    (field2 = '123' and field3 = '456')
    or (field2 = '789' and field3 = '123')
```

Comment: Wow, never would have figured that one.  Works great, thanks!